# Matter.js: Circle not accelerating down in inclined plane

Tags: javascript, matter.js

I am writing a simple simulation of a ball rolling down an inclined plane. I drop the ball and it falls to the inclined plane. As it bounces a bit, it picks up speed on the plane until the point where it stops sliding and just rolls.

When it starts to roll, the ball will slow down a bit and then roll the rest of the way at a constant speed. From that point on it will not accelerate at all unlike a normal ball on a slope.

If I set friction to 0, it will accelerate, but the ball does not roll - it just slides down the slope which isn't what I want.

I modified a codepen to show a wireframe version of this: https://codepen.io/efunneko/pen/oNdGbVz

[image: ball slows down on slope]

The ball creation is simply:

```
    Composite.add(world, Bodies.circle(width / 1.2, height / 4, 40, {restitution: 0.5}));
```

Comment: Note that I did look through all the examples for matter-js to try to find one that had a ball rolling and all I could find was the car one and it seemed to behave the same way - constant speed down a slope.

Comment: Please share your code as a [mcve], preferably a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). You can [edit] your post if you have code to add or more clarifying statements.

Comment: Thanks for the codepen, but can you put the code in the question? I can reproduce the problem. [Related MJS issue](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/issues/1158)